# How to determine in code if installed libfuse supports async io

Tags: fuse

on my application when I detect open file is fuse type I want to be able to determine if the underlying libfuse supports async io.  If it is not supported then I would fall back to sync io.  Is there a programmatic way to do that? Maybe an ioctl? or examine something under sysfs?  e.g. /sys/module/fuse/srcversion?

Comment: Can you read the version of libfuse installed and have a list to check against?

Comment: Hi.  Yeah,  I considered that approach but it is a bit klunky and slow to fork off rpm cmd then parse it out for right min version.   We are also considering just firing off a test async io to check. If it fails async io is disabled but this also has some overhead.